# Is a Variable That is Equal to a Function Considered a Global Variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, global-variables

In a question on one of my quizzes, we were asked to determine how many global variables there are in the following block of code:

```
    var one = 1;
    var two = 2;
    var multiplier = function(number){
    }
```

I answered saying there are two: **one** and **two**. However, my teacher marked it wrong and stated there are 3 global variables. Is a variable that is equal to a function still considered a global variable?

Comment: Yea, In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, which means they can be: **a)** stored in a variable, object, or array. **b)** passed as an argument to a function. **c)** returned from a function. More info [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/discover-the-power-of-first-class-functions-fd0d7b599b69)

Comment: Yes, there are 3 global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first-class in Javascript - they can be assigned to any variable. A variable can hold any value - a number (as with `one` and `two`), a string, etc, an object, *or a function*.

A global variable which happens to point to a function (as with `multiplier`) is still a global variable.

Note that function declarations on the top level create global variables as well, for example:

```js
function multiplier(number) {
}

// The function declaration created a property on the global object:
console.log(typeof window.multiplier);
// just like:
var one = 1;
console.log(typeof window.one);
```

Of course, [global variables are best avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad) when not necessary, and they're rarely necessary.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much, that was very clear and concise.